# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Proposal' when running RCNN train_end2end.py

Tags: python, mxnet

I am trying to use R-CNN in mxnet. I had a working mxnet installation. I upgraded it using git pull so I can use the latest version. Then I followed the instructions in the [github repo](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/example/rcnn) to install the additional dependencies and run the demo. Afetr I run the line

```
bash script/vgg_voc07.sh 0,1
```

I get the error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Proposal' when running RCNN train_end2end.py

This is exactly what I did:

```
    1  cd mxnet
    2  git pull
    3  cd example/rcnn
    4  ls
    5  bash script/additional_deps.sh
    6  pip install matplotlib
    7  bash script/get_voc.sh
    8  bash script/get_pretrained_model.sh
    9  bash script/vgg_voc07.sh 0,1
   10  ls
   11  cd ..
   12  sed -i 's/EXTRA_OPERATORS =/EXTRA_OPERATORS = example\/rcnn\/operator/g' config.mk
   13  make -j"$(nproc)"
   14  cd example
   15  cd rcnn
   16  make
   17  bash script/vgg_voc07.sh 0,1
```

I also posted an issue in [github](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/5102)

Answer (score 1):

There must be some additional c/c++ source files in the r-cnn git repository. You d better copy them into your mxnet source directory named as 'proposal' then compile mxnet again.